# What does "-1" means in the delivery day and delivery time of return data from UPS API

Tags: php, api, joomla, ups

I am working with **UPS API** and having a problem with the result return by **UPS API**. I am getting the result ,which look like this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 9.90
            [code] => 03
            [delivery_day] => -1
            [delivery_time] => -1
            [currency_code] => USD
            [old_currency_code] => USD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 12.70
            [code] => 12
            [delivery_day] => 3
            [delivery_time] => -1
            [currency_code] => USD
            [old_currency_code] => USD
        )
)
```

Which is perfect , But when you see in first array, delivery day and time show the value "-1". In the second array delivery day value is 3 and time is "-1" . I need to know what does it means? It is really confusing. Please help.

Comment: You got the response for 2 services, they go by code:
03: UPS Ground
12: UPS 3rd day

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the API you're using:

#### Shipping and Rating Business Processes

- Address Validation API
- Address Validation Street Level API
- Locator API
- Pickup API
- Rating API
- Shipping API
- Time in Transit API Visibility Business Processes
- UPS Quantum View® API
- Tracking API
- UPS Signature Tracking® API

#### International Trade Business Processes

- UPS TradeAbility® API

You are probably better off referring to the [UPS Developer Website](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit) and the relevant documentation, starting with the PDF of their "[Developer Kit — User Guide](http://www.ups.com/media/en/UPS_dev_kit_user_guide.pdf)"

Comment: I am using the Shipping API, and in the response return by the ups look like as above. And I don't understand what does "-1" means. Could you tell what it means?

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is showing multiple services, I would guess that you are running rates, not shipments. In addition, some other transformation is occurring which is causing the odd values that you are seeing as your code must be merging a rate response with a transit response in order to provide costs along with transit times.

Below is rate response XML from UPS:

```
<RatedShipment>
<Service>
<Code>03</Code></Service>
<BillingWeight>
<UnitOfMeasurement><Code>KGS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
<Weight>23.0</Weight>
</BillingWeight>
<TransportationCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>73.65</MonetaryValue>
</TransportationCharges>
<ServiceOptionsCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>0.00</MonetaryValue>
</ServiceOptionsCharges>
<TotalCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>73.65</MonetaryValue>
</TotalCharges>
<GuaranteedDaysToDelivery>0</GuaranteedDaysToDelivery>
<RatedPackage>
<TransportationCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>0.00</MonetaryValue>
</TransportationCharges>
<ServiceOptionsCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>0.00</MonetaryValue>
</ServiceOptionsCharges>
<TotalCharges>
<CurrencyCode>UKL</CurrencyCode>
<MonetaryValue>0.00</MonetaryValue>
</TotalCharges>
<Weight>23.0</Weight>
<BillingWeight>
<UnitOfMeasurement>
<Code>KGS</Code>
</UnitOfMeasurement>
<Weight>0.0</Weight>
</BillingWeight>
</RatedPackage>
</RatedShipment>
```

This is a partial snippet of a transit response:

```
<EstimatedArrival>
<BusinessTransitDays>1</BusinessTransitDays>
<Time>23:30:00</Time>
<PickupDate>2001-06-08</PickupDate>
<PickupTime>19:00:00</PickupTime>
<HolidayCount>0</HolidayCount>
<DelayCount>0</DelayCount>
<Date>2001-06-11</Date>
<DayOfWeek>MON</DayOfWeek>
<TotalTransitDays>2</TotalTransitDays>
<CustomerCenterCutoff>18:30:00</CustomerCenterCutoff>
<RestDays>1</RestDays>
</EstimatedArrival>
```